# Subclassing threading.Thread: Why only override __init__() and run()?

Tags: python, multithreading

Why is the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects) of Python's threading library insisting so strongly on overriding only `__init__()` and `run()`?

See the bold part here:

> This class represents an activity that is run in a separate thread of
>   control. There are two ways to specify the activity: by passing a
>   callable object to the constructor, or by overriding the `run()`
>   method in a subclass. **No other methods (except for the constructor)
>   should be overridden in a subclass. In other words, only override the
>   `__init__()` and `run()` methods of this class.**

The Thread class does not have too many methods per se. So, I'd assume it boils down to `start` or `join` as candidates for overriding (`name`, `ident`, `isAlive`, and `daemon` don't make much sense, I guess - I might be wrong!) So, an answer could - for instance - give an example of what happens (and goes wrong?!) when either of those two is overridden.

Comment: In addition to [Ned's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51465732/3789550), you  should read the source code and try to rationalize things with the doc.

Comment: I suspect the reason for the recommendation that only `__init__` and `run` be overridden in child classes is because those two methods do not require any synchronization. The `__init__` method runs only in the parent thread, while the `run` method runs only in the new child thread, after it's been started. Methods like `start` and `join` need to have their behaviors well defined with respect to multiple threads, and use internal synchronization objects to make sure their state remains consistent. It would be hard for you to replicate the synchronization in an overridden version of the methods.

Comment: I see your point, but wouldn't it be sufficient to (for instance) call `super().join()` in the overridden `join()`?

Answer (score 0):

The author of the class gets to decide what the public API is.  This class isn't designed to have other methods overridden.

Comment: So, you basically say "there is a reason, but I don't know it"...? That's not exactly an answer, is it?

Comment: It's true that I don't know the author's reasoning.  You are looking for a deeper answer than I have. I don't know what level the OP is looking for.

Comment: Well, the `Thread` class does not have too many methods per se. So, I'd assume it boils down to `start` or `join` as candidates for overriding (`name`, `ident`, `isAlive`, and `daemon` don't make much sense, I guess - I might be wrong!) So, an answer could - for instance - give an example of what happens (and goes wrong?!) when either of those two is overridden?